# Problem with creating EBS snapshot on server(Linux EC2 instance)

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am working on a task that required to run a script on a server, The script will grab instance id, create snapshot and run `yum update -y` command and reboot the server.

```html
#!/bin/bash

set -eu

# Set Vars
AWS_ACCOUNT_ID=$(aws sts get-caller-identity --query Account --output text)
export REGION=$(curl --silent http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone | sed 's/[a-z]$//')
export INSTANCE_ID=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
echo $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID
echo $REGION

# Fetch VolumeId 
volumeid=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --region $REGION --instance-id "$INSTANCE_ID" --filters Name=instance-state-name,Values=running  --query "Reservations[*].Instances[].[BlockDeviceMappings[*].{VolumeName:Ebs.VolumeId}]" --output text)

echo $INSTANCE_ID
echo $volumeid

# Create snapshot
aws ec2 create-snapshot --region $REGION --volume-id $volumeid --description "Test-Snapshot-$INSTANCE_ID" 
read -p "waiting a while to complete creation of EBS snapshot" -t 100
echo -e "\x1B[01;36m Snapshot has been created \x1B[0m"
```

I can get the Instance id but when I am trying to create snapshot id from Instance id, I am getting following error:

**ERROR**

```
us-east-1

An error occurred (UnauthorizedOperation) when calling the DescribeInstances operation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.
```

Thank you so much in advance for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your instance, and with that your script is missing the `ec2:DescribeInstances` permission to run the `aws ec2 describe-instances` command.

You should attach that permission to the instance role that is assigned to the instance (or create a new role with the permissions attached if there is none assigned yet).

Comment: Thanks Christian Let me have a look again in IAM role.

Answer (score 0):

Your IAM permissions do not grant access to DescribeInstances.

If you’re using an IAM role for the instance check it’s policies.

If it’s a user then make sure the credentials are being retrieved, either via aws credentials file or via environment variable